# How can i remove this Segmentation fault in C Program

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, stack-overflow

here i want to solve stack overflow issue in this code.
here in this code i call function p recursively 350000 times so i got segmentation fault
when i remove 350000 and put 300000 than it works fine
here segmentation fault comes because of i calling recursively call of function p more times or calling a recursive function too deep.

this is not working because i take `if(i != 350000)`.
its stop at may be in this range 300000 to 327480. i tested 10 times

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void p(char *, int);

int main() 
{
    char *a = "HI";
    int b = 10;
    p(a, b);
    printf("\nComplete");
    return 0;

}
void p(char *a, int b) 
{
    static long int i = 0;

    if (i != 350000) 
    {
        printf("\n%ld \t at Hi hello", i);
        i++;
        p(a, b);
    } else 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

when i check this code using valgrind tool than valgraind reporting error like this

```
==9236== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0x7fe801ff8
==9236== 
==9236== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==9236==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FE801FF8
==9236==    at 0x4EA012E: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1276)
==9236==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==9236==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==9236==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==9236==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==9236==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==9236== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0x7fe801ff0
==9236== 
==9236== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==9236==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FE801FF0
==9236==    at 0x4A2269F: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)
==9236==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==9236==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==9236==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==9236==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==9236==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Please help me guys i really want this issue solution. and i cant remove recursively call of function from my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stacks are *not* an unlimited resource. Recursion lends itself well to algorithms which reduce their search space relatively quickly (binary chop of a sorted array, binary or multi-way tree traversal and so on).

If you find yourself with an algorithm that requires recursion to the level of three hundred and fifty *thousand* times, you really should reconsider using a recursive solution.

For example, something like:

```
def addUnsigned (a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    return addUnsigned (a-1, b+1)
```

is *not* a good match for recursion.

If you *really* cannot remove the recursion, then you need to do what valgrind suggests, change the stack size. For example, the linkage editor on my system, `ld`, has a `--stack` option which allows you to specify the reserved (and,optionally, committed) stack size.

Comment: So how can i know the current stack size  and reset the stack size programmatically

Comment: You don't do it in the program, it's generally done by the linker or loader. Seriously, you need to revisit your need for recursion.

Comment: Reply me...how can i do this?

Comment: if you use MACRO instead of thet function then ?

Comment: Sam, you need to look into the options for your linker. If you're using `ld`, try `ld --help` to get the options. You'll probably find something there that can specify stack size. If you're asking how to turn a recursive solution into an iterative one, that's best asked in a separate question.

Comment: thanx man i set this. but now my program takes more than 32MB stack size to run the program so its efficient in Embedded or not??

Comment: Sam: if you're embedded platform is a 64-bit CPU with bucketloads of memory then yes, it's fine :-) Otherwise not so good. I still think you should be looking away from the recursive solution. 350K stack frames is way too much for a recursive solution.

Comment: Paxdiablo But i must have to use this recursive solution. i can use goto and label in this code but in my original code i want to maintain previous state value in function. i had implemented huffman decoding function. in this i have to traverse huffman encoded tree. so i must have to use this recursive solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for help i learn some new things from your answer

Comment: i got solution and apply another way, left the recursive call way.

Answer (score 1):

With that particular example, if you turn up the optimisation level of your compiler sufficiently high it should perform tail call elimination, which will solve the stack overflow problem (for example, gcc 4.4.5 does so at `-O2` and above).

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to control it  programmatically, you can call your function in a thread and set the stack size for the thread (and wait till the thread completes).