# Can I use macro instead of recursion to avoid segmantion fault?

Tags: c

This is an extended question from

[How can i remove this Segmentation fault in C Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963150/how-can-i-remove-this-segmentation-fault-in-c-program)

here segmentation fault occur because of stack overflow due to recursion so manny times

so i have changed his code like this..

**make a MACRO insted of that function so function call is removed**

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void p(char *a, int b); 


#define MAGIC(a,b)  p(a,b) 

void p(char *a, int b) 
{
    static long int i = 0;

    if (i != 350000) 
    {
        printf("\n%ld \t at Hi hello", i);
        i++;
        return MAGIC(a, b);
    } else 
    {
        return;
    }
}


int main() 
{
    char *a = "HI";
    int b = 10;
    MAGIC(a, b);
    printf("\nComplete");
    return 0;

}
```

still i am getting segmentation fault ...still stack overflow.... why?

Comment: What exactly do you want the program to do, and why? Why not just use a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `return MAGIC(a, b);` to

`goto START;` and add a `START` label in the beginning of the function.

Edit:

Example using a `while` loop:

```
void p(char *a, int b) 
{
    static long int i = 0;

    while (i != 350000) 
    {
        printf("\n%ld \t at Hi hello", i);
        i++;
    } 
}
```

Example using a `for` loop:

```
void p(char *a, int b) 
{
    long int i = 0; // static seems wrong here

    for (;i != 350000; i++) 
    {
        printf("\n%ld \t at Hi hello", i);
    } 
}
```

Comment: HEY MAN  its worked..but does goto is dangerous to embedded system ?

Comment: `goto` is only dangerous if (ab)used incorrectly. All loops are just syntax sugar for `goto`. You could rewrite your code to use a `while` or `for` loop to make it 'prettier'.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not work. A macro is just a text copy-paste, so the result is still the same.

So your code will be expanded as:

```
void p(char *a, int b) 
{
    static long int i = 0;

    if (i != 350000) 
    {
        printf("\n%ld \t at Hi hello", i);
        i++;
        return p(a, b);
    } else 
    {
        return;
    }
}


int main() 
{
    char *a = "HI";
    int b = 10;
    p(a, b);
    printf("\nComplete");
    return 0;

}
```

which still has the recursion and will likely stackoverflow.

**EDIT : One way to redesign the algorithm is as follows:**

```
void p(char *a, int b) 
{
    long int i = 0;

    while (i != 350000)
    {
        printf("\n%ld \t at Hi hello", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: ya i am avaoiding function call ..i am just copying function code into macro ..so do not use stack

Comment: so how can i use macro here to avaoid function call? is it possible ?

Comment: In short you can't, unless you redesign the algorithm to some extent.

Comment: @Mysticial: Your `while` loop is wrong. You need to omit the `return p(a,b);` part :)